# Approximate value of polynomial in minimum bit operations

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

Given a real polynomial equation of degree d, I want to estimate the sign of f(a) for some a. As in check if f(a) is positive or negative.
How can I do that with minimum bit operations?

Comment: What do you mean by 'minimum bit operations'?

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is a polynomial I don't think you can find the sign of $p(a)$ without evaluating it at $a$.

You can evaluate a polynomial at a point, with an optimum number of multiplications and additions using a formula known as Horner's rule.

Let $p(x) = a_n x^n + \ldots + a_1 x + a_0 = (\ldots(a_n x + a_{n-1})x + a_{n-2})x + ... + p_1)x +p_0$.

Using this recursive formula you can evaluate $p$ at any point with $n$ multiplications and $n$ additions.

If you need the sign of $p(a)$ to solve a polynomial equation using Bisection you may want to check the [Newton Iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) because it converges to a root much faster than bisection.